# Android M NFC permission issue

Tags: android, nfc

In my app I require the permission : `android.permission.NFC`, and I've read that NFC is granted by default, but after running it on the new AndroidM OS I notice in settings that users can actually disable a permission called `NFC-Near Field Communication`.

The problem is even if I disable it from settings, I still have it as granted when I try `checkSelfPermission`, and my app crashes because it doesn't have NFC permission, that's just weird.

Can someone point out what's wrong ?

I also have the following permissions related to NFC:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC_TRANSACTION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.gsma.services.nfc.permission.TRANSACTION_EVENT" />
<uses-permission android:name="nfc.hci.permission.TRANSACTION_EVENT" />
```

If I try to request any of these, I automatically get the callback method executed with a `DENIED` response.

Thank you for your answers

Comment: May I know your AndroidM version i.e. preview 1, preview 2 or preview 3?

Comment: that may sound kinda stupid :D but where can I see this info ? all I see is 'android version: M'

Comment: In Androd Studio, go File > Settings > Android SDK. here you can see the list of all the available SDKs. Here check the API level. For latest release i.e. preview 3, API level should be 23. If it is not then update your Android SDK and most important if you have device for testing then flash preview 3 because this is the most stable Android M version.

Comment: I'm actually using Eclipse and I'm pretty sure I'm using the latest release (I don't see any new revisions on Android SDK Manager), but the phone though I'm not sure what preview it is (I got it with android M pre installed)

Comment: Preview 1: MPZ44Q Preview 3: MPA44I - just check in your device settings which one you have. I could not find Preview 2 build number. Only in Preview 3 the "Build.VERSION_CODES.M" returns 23, else it returns 22.

Comment: I have this: p1_global_com-userdebug M MRA26 15....... some numbers, I guess it's preview 2 (because of MRA26)

Comment: Preview 2 was very unstable and was having many abnormal behaviors. So suggest you to flash preview 3 and check the behavior. I am pretty sure that in preview 3 you will not find enable/disable option for NFC permission in settings

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is not expected. Looks you are using (System Image flashed on your device or old `SDK` on your `IDE`) `Android M` < `Preview 3` (Final SDK). I have verified using sample app (**preview 3 (Final SDK) + Nexus 5 (system image preview 3)**) and found that there is no revocable option for NFC permission. Please verify using latest environment.